# Create a PDF by passing HTML content to a method

Tags: c#

Create a PDF by passing HTML content to a method.
I want to do this is c#.  Is there a utility I can use?

Comment: I googled "c# create pdf from html" and found some good starting points.

Comment: This site is starting to suck with all the questions that could be answered by searching the web.

Comment: the reason is not to google it before asking. I collect information first, you can improve your question and your answers though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wkhtmtopdf. It is the best tool I have found so far.

For .NET, you may use this small library to easily invoke wkhtmtopdf command line utility.

links:

http://wkhtmltopdf.org/

https://github.com/codaxy/wkhtmltopdf

Answer (score 0):

[Essential PDF](http://asp.syncfusion.com/demos/web/pdf/htmltopdf.aspx) can convert HTML to PDF. It is written in C# and available as a library for use from any .NET platform.

The [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) provides the whole suite of products for free if you qualify.

Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Answer (score 0):

HiQPdf Software offers a [free HTML to PDF Converter for .NET](http://www.hiqpdf.com/free-html-to-pdf-converter.aspx) you can use to produce small and medium PDF documents for free. For large PDFs or for advanced features you can upgrade at any time to professional version.

I am a HiQPdf Support representative. The relevant code from that page is copied below:

```
protected void buttonConvertToPdf_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // create the HTML to PDF converter
    HtmlToPdf htmlToPdfConverter = new HtmlToPdf();

    // set browser width
    htmlToPdfConverter.BrowserWidth = int.Parse(textBoxBrowserWidth.Text);

    // set browser height if specified, otherwise use the default
    if (textBoxBrowserHeight.Text.Length > 0)
        htmlToPdfConverter.BrowserHeight = int.Parse(textBoxBrowserHeight.Text);

    // set HTML Load timeout
    htmlToPdfConverter.HtmlLoadedTimeout = int.Parse(textBoxLoadHtmlTimeout.Text);

    // set PDF page size and orientation
    htmlToPdfConverter.Document.PageSize = GetSelectedPageSize();
    htmlToPdfConverter.Document.PageOrientation = GetSelectedPageOrientation();

    // set PDF page margins
    htmlToPdfConverter.Document.Margins = new PdfMargins(0);

    // set a wait time before starting the conversion
    htmlToPdfConverter.WaitBeforeConvert = int.Parse(textBoxWaitTime.Text);

    // convert HTML to PDF
    byte[] pdfBuffer = null;

    if (radioButtonConvertUrl.Checked)
    {
        // convert URL to a PDF memory buffer
        string url = textBoxUrl.Text;

        pdfBuffer = htmlToPdfConverter.ConvertUrlToMemory(url);
    }
    else
    {
        // convert HTML code
        string htmlCode = textBoxHtmlCode.Text;
        string baseUrl = textBoxBaseUrl.Text;

        // convert HTML code to a PDF memory buffer
        pdfBuffer = htmlToPdfConverter.ConvertHtmlToMemory(htmlCode, baseUrl);
    }

    // inform the browser about the binary data format
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");

    // let the browser know how to open the PDF document, attachment or inline, and the file name
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("{0}; filename=HtmlToPdf.pdf; size={1}",
        checkBoxOpenInline.Checked ? "inline" : "attachment", pdfBuffer.Length.ToString()));

    // write the PDF buffer to HTTP response
    HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(pdfBuffer);

    // call End() method of HTTP response to stop ASP.NET page processing
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
```